# vb.net programmatically cancel editig datagridview cell

Tags: vb.net

I'm new in vb.net and have a problem with cancel cell edit in data grid view.

I want to have edit property for whole data grid view set on `true` but on "double click" event I want to run some code and in the end cancel cell editing (blinking cursor).

On VBA to do this in Excel i type `cancel = true`.

What would be the formula for vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CancelEdit method on CellMouseDoubleClick Event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDoubleClick

    DataGridView1.CancelEdit()

End Sub
```